# Archive of 1,000s of web-pages (that is occupying too much space)

Tags: archiving

I have to manage a collection of web-pages that's increasing daily. The space they occupy is starting to become  a nuisance.

There is no interest in how exactly they look like, so I deleted a series of font files. I keep the CSS, because they are really small and deleting them would alter the pages too much.

I decided to delete all font files. Basically I delete files matching: .woff .woff2 .eot .ttf .otf * font*.svgz imgad imgad.dat * webfont *. However I still see font files like TabletGothic-Bold.svg and such, which are rather big (close to 1MB, but multiply that by several 1,000).

How can I find all other font files? Is the list exhaustive?

What else could I do to make them occupy less space?

Answer (score 0):

Try different [compression mechanisms](http://www.peazip.org/peazip-compression-benchmark.html). Though I find text files shrink to about 10% of their original size using Zip/deflate, [7Z](https://www.howtogeek.com/200698/benchmarked-whats-the-best-file-compression-format/) or [IZarc](https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=558955) might do better yet.

Of course, be sure the archiving tool can be used on all OS's in your environment.